# How to Check duplicate records in table using ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to send an alert if there is no records in destination table after copy activity is completed. right now I am try with lookup activity along with if activity but getting this below error

Operation on target Alert If no records in activity ts failed: The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more simple.
Add an variable to you pipeline, varError.
In your lookup, add a select count(*) from your_table
Add an activity "Set variable" where you set the variable to

`@string(div(100, int(activity('IsRecordExist').output.firstrow.yourColumn)))`

This will do an device by 0 if no values are copied, and cause the pipeline to fail.
You can then sett up a monitor for pipeline failed that sends you an alert.